# Formula not returning information to cell, just shows the formula

Tags: windows, windows-10

```
=IF(left(T1,10)="ID: msanta","Manuel",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: mbrown","Melissa",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: adarli","Annette",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: mrivas","Melody",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: wgorma","Wynema, IF(left(T1,11)=B6: jponsar","PA",IF(left(T1,12)="ID: lkrieger","PA",IF(left(T1,11)="ID: ltruong","PA",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: pboyer","PA",IF(left(T1,11)="ID: fberaki","PA", IF(LEFT(T1,9)="ID: pbelt","PA", IF(LEFT(T1,11)="ID: plee013","PA",IF(left(T1,3)="ID:","WIP by Others")))))))))))))"
```

Comment: Change the cell formatting from Text to General.  You may need to re-paste the formula in afterwords.

Comment: The formula, in general, is not correct (several incorrect spaces or missing parentheses). First, fix the formula and then try it.

Comment: You don't specify what application you're using, there is no information on what the cell references refer to or what the data looks like (assuming this is some spreadsheet), and no explanation.  Just a ridiculously long formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing formatting from the cell, and then re-adding the formula. Also, I'm pretty sure that it just shows the formula if Excel (I assume) encounters an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in the formula itself, all together might certainly cause Excel (at least when you Paste it into the cell without Editing the cell) to not recognize it as a formula at all.

I think that the correct formula is supposed to be:
`=IF(left(T1,10)="ID: msanta","Manuel",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: mbrown","Melissa",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: adarli","Annette",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: mrivas","Melody",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: wgorma","Wynema",IF(left(T1,11)="ID: jponsar","PA",IF(left(T1,12)="ID: lkrieger","PA",IF(left(T1,11)="ID: ltruong","PA",IF(left(T1,10)="ID: pboyer","PA",IF(left(T1,11)="ID: fberaki","PA", IF(LEFT(T1,9)="ID: pbelt","PA", IF(LEFT(T1,11)="ID: plee013","PA",IF(left(T1,3)="ID:","WIP by Others")))))))))))))`

You can try this one.

(The errors in the formula include: Quotation mark at the end of all parentheses, *B6: jponsar"* instead of *"ID: jponsar"*,*"Wynema* missing quotation mark.)